# Cactus (Prototype) - A game engine for text-based adventure games

Tags: python, game, library, adventure-game

[@Annonomus Penguin](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/220/annonomus-penguin), [@QPaysTaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863564/qpaystaxes), and I are building an engine for easy creation of text-based adventure games, like Zork. The engine is still in its early stages of development, and the following code is my prototype. Here's the library code.

---

**`cactus.py`**

```
class MapPosition(object):
    """
    Describes data about a position on in the world
    map. Contains the following data attributes.

        name     - The name of the choice.
        desc     - A description of the choice.
        choices  - A dictionary of possible choices.
        function - An (optional) function to be run.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, desc, choices, function=None):
        self.name     = name
        self.desc     = desc
        self.choices  = choices
        self.function = function

    def print_choice(self):
        """
        Outputs certain data about the choice, e.g, description,
        it's name, possible choices, etc.
        """
        if self.choices != {}:
            print "{0}: {1} Choices: {2}".format(
                self.name,
                self.desc,
                ', '.join([key for key, value in self.choices.iteritems()])
            )
        else:
            print "{0}: {1}".format(
                self.name,
                self.desc
            )

    def run_function(self):
        """
        Run the attached function when the choice is chosen
        by the user.
        """
        if self.function is not None:
            self.function()


class GameMap(object):
    """
    Describes data about a world map. Contains the
    following data attributes.

        map_data - A list containing MapPosition's
    """
    def __init__(self, map_data):
        self.map_data = map_data

    def find_start(self):
        """
        This iterates over the self.map_data list and finds
        the starting choice.
        """
        for index, choice in enumerate(self.map_data):
            if choice.name.lower() == "start":
                return index
            else:
                continue

    def return_map(self):
        """
        Returns the map_data as a list.
        """
        return self.map_data


class MainGame(object):
    """
    Describes data about the game itself. Contains
    the following data attributes.

        name        - The name of the game.
        desc        - The intro text to be printed.
        prompt      - The prompt to use during gameplay.
        game_map    - A GameMap instance containing map data.
    """
    def __init__(self, name, desc, prompt, game_map):
        self.name         = name
        self.desc         = desc
        self.prompt       = prompt
        self.game_map     = game_map
        self.map_data     = game_map.return_map()
        self.start_index  = game_map.find_start()
        self.map_position = self.start_index

    def play_game(self):
        """
        Start playing the game. This function will find the
        MapPosition element that has the name "start". Do note,
        user input is lowered, but a check is also done on non-
        lowered input.
        """
        print self.name
        print self.desc

        while True:
            current_position = self.map_data[self.map_position]
            possible_choices = current_position.choices

            current_position.print_choice()
            current_position.run_function()

            user_input = raw_input(self.prompt)

            if user_input.lower() in possible_choices:
                self.map_position = possible_choices[user_input.lower()]
            elif user_input in possible_choices:
                self.map_position = possible_choices[user_input]
```

---

Before I show the example file, here's a small "tutorial" on how to create a small game.

- First off, create a `GameMap` instance. This instance will hold `MapPosition` instances stored in an list.

---

```
GAME_MAP = cactus.GameMap([
    # ...
])
```

---

- Next, fill the list inside `GameMap` with `MapPosition` instances. A `MapPosition` instance contains the following data.

  - A name for the position. (Note, any `MapPosition` with the name `"start"` will be the starting position for the game).
  - A description of the position.
  - Other possible `MapPosition` instances that the player can choose.
  - An optional function to be run.

---

```
cactus.MapPosition(
    "position name",
    "position description",
    {
        "a choice": 1 # <-- References the index of another position.
    }
    function=a_func # <-- If no function is referenced, default is None.
)
```

---

- Finally, an instance of `MainGame` is created with the following data.

  - The name of the game.
  - A description of the game.
  - The prompt to be used in the game.
  - The game map, and instance of `GameMap`.

---

```
GAME = cactus.MainGame(
    "game name",
    "game description",
    "game prompt",
    GAME_MAP
)
```

---

- Finally, after all that has been done, call `GAME.play_game()`, and play your game.

For those who also want a concrete example of a simple game, the following program demonstrates that.

---

```
import cactus
from sys import exit

GAME_MAP = cactus.GameMap([
    cactus.MapPosition(
        "Start",
        "Welcome to the test!",
        {
            "left":  1,
            "right": 2,
        }
    ),
    cactus.MapPosition(
        "Left",
        "You took the left path and lived!",
        {},
        function=exit
    ),
    cactus.MapPosition(
        "Right",
        "You took the right path and died!",
        {},
        function=exit
    )
])

GAME = cactus.MainGame(
    "Test Game",
    "This is a simple test game! Yay!",
    "> ",
    GAME_MAP
)

GAME.play_game()
```

---

Finally, for those who are interested, here's the [Official Cactus Discussion Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24299/discussion-about-cactus), and here's the link to the [official project on Github](https://github.com/ShearOfDoom).

Comment: It looks good! Not as good as mine will, but good! (Rampant narcissism aside, I like it)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Thanks, I appreciate the feedback! :)

Comment: So if you wanted a thorough game, you'd have a multiple nests inside each MapPosition call, correct? It seems as though you'll end up with one huge file in the end with tens or hundreds of layers nested deep! Am I wrong?

Comment: @AlexL No... Not neccisarily. Each `MapPosition` contains a dictionary of user choices which reference the index of another `MapPosition` in the `GameMap` array.

Comment: It seems that `MainGame` does not need to be a class, but could rather be implemented as a function.

Comment: @jme Hmm, yeah, now that I'm looking at it, I'm realizing that it probably shouldn't be a class, e.g, it's only `__init__` and one function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
else:
    continue
```

Does nothing: remove it.

**`lower` or not `lower`: you must decide**

I suggest you decide: either all input is lowercased or it is kept as the original, the following is not a clean solution (you can understand it is not clean because you spelled it out in the docs).

```
if user_input.lower() in possible_choices:
    self.map_position = possible_choices[user_input.lower()]
elif user_input in possible_choices:
    self.map_position = possible_choices[user_input]
```

Comment: Hmm, could I specify an option where the user can choose to have text lowered? Would that be cleaner?

Comment: @EthanBierlein in fact I think you should use a keyword argument: this way beginners will have the text automatically lowercased and experts would be able to differentiate `desert` and `DESERT` and `Desert` may they decide to.